# How to safely remove global.asax from web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service asp.net project which has a global.asax with empty `Application_Start` and `Application_End` implementations.
As far as I can understand, in this case it is of no use and could be removed (correct me if I'm wrong).
Do I need to do anything other than delete global.asax and global.asax.cs (such as change something in web.config or in the project settings)?
Just asking in order to not screw up some dependencies I'm not aware of...

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. You could exclude the file from the project (Right click file=>Exclude from project) to made sure nothing crashes before permanently deleting the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you shouldn't have any problems just deleting the file.  But, if you are concerned you will 'break' something, try renaming it first.